# typescript-eslint/pre-commit hook (monorepo): Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser

Tags: typescript, eslint, pre-commit-hook, typescript-eslint, pre-commit.com

We recently migrated to a monorepo and we are still trying to set everything up. We use typescript and eslint with prettier. The structure is the following:

```
root
  - common
    - folder_a
      - file_a.ts
  - build_scripts
    - script_a.js
  - project_a
    - components
      - component_a
        - Component.tsx
    - tsconfig.json
    - .eslintrc.json
    - node_modules
    - package.json
  - .prettierignore
  - .prettierrc.yml
  - .eslintignore
  - .eslintrc.base.json
  - tsconfig.base.json
  - node_modules
  - package.json
  - Makefile
  - webpack.config.js
  - .pre-commit-config.yaml
```

The `common` folder contains code that is used across multiple projects and isn't considered a project of its own (no tsconfig.json). All sub-projects that contain their own tsconfig.json and .eslintrc.json file, are extending the base ones, as you can see below:

**tsconfig.base.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["ES2017", "DOM"],
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "paths": {
            "@common/*": ["./common/*"]
        }
    },
    // include all projects that don't have their own
    // tsconfig.json file AND need to be compiled/linted
    // => very important because typescript-eslint will
    // otherwise load ALL files in memory for type-checking
    // and consequently eslint will crash with an OOM error
    "include": ["common/**/*"]
}
```

**.eslintrc.base.json (rules omitted for brevity)**

```
{
    "env": {
        "es2020": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:destructuring/recommended",
        "airbnb-base",
        "prettier",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "project": "./tsconfig.base.json",
        "ecmaVersion": 11,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "prettier",
        "@typescript-eslint",
        "destructuring"
    ],
    "rules": {}
}
```

**.eslintignore**

```
*/**/build
Makefile
**/*.js
**/*.json
```

**.pre-commit-config.yaml** (taken from the example in https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/466#issuecomment-274282684)

```
- repo: local
  hooks:
    - id: lint_fix
      name: lint_fix_project_a
      entry: node_modules/.bin/eslint --report-unused-disable-directives --fix -c project_a/.eslintrc.json --ext .ts,.tsx
      files: ^project_a/
      types: [file]
      language: node
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.2.2",,
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.15.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.15.1",
    "eslint": "7.20.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "14.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "6.10.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "14.1.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-destructuring": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "4.0.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.5.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.2.0",
    "express": "4.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.1.2",
    "typescript": "3.9.7"
  }
}
```

**project_a/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2017", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@common/*": ["../common/*"],
      "@components/*": ["./components/*"]
    }
  },
  // overwrite the base "includes"
  "include": ["**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/*",
    "**/build/*"
  ]
}
```

**project_a/.eslintrc.json (rules omitted for brevity)**

```
{
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:destructuring/recommended",
        "airbnb",
        "airbnb/hooks",
        "prettier",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "prettier/react",
        "../.eslintrc.base.json"
    ],
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "node": false
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "project": "./tsconfig.json",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "plugins": [
        "prettier",
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint",
        "destructuring"
    ],
    "rules": {}
}
```

Bundling `project_a` with `webpack`, using `ts-loader`, `eslint-webpack-plugin` and `project_a/tsconfig.json` works perfectly fine. No linting errors reported. Same for VSCode, the vscode-eslint extension doesn't report anything.

Also running the following inside `project_a` is successful without any linting errors.

> ../node_modules/.bin/eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx --fix -c .eslintrc.json

**However**, when changing a file in `project_a` and trying to stage and commit, the following error is thrown:

> /home/web/project_a/components/component_a/Component.tsx
>
> 0:0  error  Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for
> @typescript-eslint/parser. The file does not match your project
> config: project_a/components/component_a/Component.tsx.
>
> The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided

It makes no sense to me, why this error would only be thrown in that specific use-case, when linting via the pre-commit hook. Also, it's very peculiar, since `project_a/tsconfig.json` `include`s all files in that folder (except `node_modules` and `build` artifacts).

```
"include": ["**/*"]
```

It seems to me it might be related to us having added

```
"include": ["common/**/*"]
```

in `./tsconfig.json`. That was added (as per the comment), because having a file from `common` open in VSCode and trying to save some changes, would make eslint crash, since according to various sources, the `@typescript-eslint/parser` would include all files in memory to gather type information for linting.

All related Github issues just mention that the file in question is just not included, as per the error itslef, but I don't see how this is happening in my scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that `@typescript-eslint/parser` resolves the provided `tsconfig.json` relative to the current working directory, which I missed while reading the docs. Thus, since the pre-commit hook is always run from the root directory, it was using `tsconfig.base.json` instead of the one in `project_a`.

In order to fix this, the following steps need to be taken (according to https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/251#issuecomment-567365174):

- rename `project_a/.eslintrc.json` to `project_a/.eslintrc.js`
- add `parserOptions.tsconfigRootDir` like the following:
- ```
  module.exports = {
    parserOptions: {
      project: './tsconfig.json'
      tsconfigRootDir: __dirname // important option
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

your configuration:

```yaml
- repo: local
  hooks:
    - id: lint_fix
      name: lint_fix_project_a
      entry: node_modules/.bin/eslint --report-unused-disable-directives --fix -c project_a/.eslintrc.json --ext .ts,.tsx
      files: ^project_a/
      types: [file]
      language: node
```

uses `language: node` which is a *managed* envinronment (`pre-commit` will create its own separate isolated node environment and use that -- and won't have access to your dependencies)

you probably want `language: system` since you are managing the environment external to pre-commit

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Same error still occurs unfortunately

Comment: hooks will also be run from the root of the repository, so the equivalent `entry` should succeed from there

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean with `so the equivalent entry should succeed from there`

Comment: cd to the root of the repository and run the `entry` with at least one filename after it and that's equivalent to what's happening here (independent of `pre-commit`) -- iterate on that until it succeeds

Comment: I now get the same error, thanks for the explanation. But it still doesn't explain the inconsistencies of the lint result, when ran from the root and from the project folder

Comment: a guess: eslint resolves files relative to the working directory instead of the project file _for some options_

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful hint! I found the issue, will write an answer soon!